# R data frame column with JSON string - need to make JSON objects columns

Tags: r, json, dataframe

So the data frame has a column (category) that is JSON. Here is a sample

```
{"id":254,"name":"Performances","slug":"dance/performances","position":1,"parent_id":6,"parent_name":"Dance","color":10917369,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/dance/performances"}}}
```

And I am having a difficult time taking some of the json objects and turning them into features of the data frame.

EXAMPLE: I would really like the dataframe['parent_cat'] to contain the JSON value of "parent_name" from the dataframe['category'].

Below is my attempt with apply, but as you can see one of the records returns a list.

```
json <- function(r){
  return(data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(txt=r['category']),stringsAsFactors=F)$name)
}

json2 <- function(df){
  data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(df$category),stringsAsFactors=F)$parent_name
}

df$child_cat <- apply(df, 1,json)

df$parent_cat <- apply(df,1,json2)

head(df[c("child_cat","parent_cat","category")])

child_cat
<chr>
                   parent_cat
                     <list>
1   Performances    <chr [1]>   
2   Hardware    <chr [1]>   
3   Software    <chr [1]>   
4   Anthologies <chr [1]>   
5   Experimental    <chr [1]>   
6   Software    <chr [1]>
```

Ive tried to use dplyr, but I get stuck with the same result for each record.... At least it is not a list! Maybe dplyr just needs a small adjustment?

```
json <- function(r){
  return(data.frame(fromJSON(r),stringsAsFactors=F)$name)
}

json2 <- function(r){
  return(data.frame(fromJSON(r),stringsAsFactors=F)$parent_name)
}

df2 <- 
    df %>% 
    mutate(p = json(category),
           c = json2(category))

head(df2[c("p","c")])

p
<chr>
                     c
                    <chr>
1   Performances    Dance       
2   Performances    Dance       
3   Performances    Dance       
4   Performances    Dance       
5   Performances    Dance       
6   Performances    Dance
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` so that we can reproduce the same thing as you have here?

Answer (score 1):

The `tidyjson` package may be what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyjson)

df <- tibble(category = '{"id":254,"name":"Performances","slug":"dance/performances","position":1,"parent_id":6,"parent_name":"Dance","color":10917369,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/dance/performances"}}}')

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(cat_parent = category %>% 
           spread_all() %>%
           pull(parent_name),
         cat_child = category %>% 
           spread_all() %>%
           pull(name))
```

This might help to check if a character in the column is not a valid json input.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyjson)
library(jsonlite)

df <- tibble(category = c('{"id":254,"name":"Performances","slug":"dance/performances","position":1,"parent_id":6,"parent_name":"Dance","color":10917369,"urls":{"web":{"discover":"http://www.kickstarter.com/discover/categories/dance/performances"}}}', 
                          'not_json'))

df <- df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(check_json = validate(category),
         cat_parent = ifelse(check_json, 
                              category %>% 
                                spread_all() %>%
                                pull(parent_name), 
                             NA))
```

Comment: Hi Chris, for a column each row contained a JSON string. Some columns where not JSON though. That’s why I used rowwise() in the answer I provided. Tidyjson looks good too, I’m sure if using rowwise() it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the mutate operation to work with the rowwise() function. I also had issues reading the JSON. Sometimes the JSON was incomplete and it caused some of the columns to return the incorrect number of rows, breaking the mutate function. so I threw it in a trycatch block and returned "Undefined" on error or warning. I also make sure the JSON object exist and is indeed a string before it is returned, or return undefined. This code may be useful for anyone wanting to read JSON char data from a data.frame column.

```
json <- function(r, str){
    df <- tryCatch({
            data.frame(fromJSON(r),stringsAsFactors=F)
          }, warning = function(war) {
            return("undefined")
          }, error = function(err) {
            return("undefined")
          }, finally = {
     })
    if(!is.data.frame(df) || !str %in% colnames(df) || !is.character(df[[str]])){
        return("undefined")
    }
    return(df[[str]])
}

df1 <- df1 %>%
       rowwise() %>%
       mutate(cat_parent = json(category,"parent_name"),
              cat_child = json(category,"name"),
              city = json(location,"name"))
```